# Local pointer arrays in CUDA global function

Tags: c++, cuda

i'm new to CUDA. Can somebody explain me please why this code is invalid? I'm trying to run it on GT240 videocard and memory checker shows me an access violation error on line with buf[0][0].

Here's the code:

```
__global__ void addKernel(char *c)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;

    if(i < 1) {
        char* buf[2];
        char some[3] = "ab";
        char another[3] = "cd";

        buf[0] = some;
        buf[1] = another;

        c[i] = buf[0][0];
    }
}
```

Thanks.

UPDATE:
Possible solution to compute something in one function and pass results to other function is to store data in global memory (1.x computation), like that:

```
__device__ char* buf[2];
__device__ char some[3];
__device__ char another[3];

__global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;

    if(i < 1) {
        some[0] = 'a';
        some[1] = 'b';

        another[0] = 'c';
        another[1] = 'd';

        buf[0] = some;
        buf[1] = another;

        buf[0][0] = 'b';
        c[i] = 1;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) problem, made worse by the fact that on your GT240, `buff` will be stored in registers or local memory, and `c` in global memory. Pointers are not portable in compute 1.x devices.

What you are trying to do is illegal in at least 2 different ways in the programming model/hardware you have, and can never be made to work.

Comment: Ok, thats make sense. But what's wrong with buf[0][0] = 'b'; line?

Comment: With `buf[0][0]='b'` compiler optimization will get rid of the complete contents of the kernel (because nothing contributes to a global memory write). So I would not say that case "works fine", only that you can't make that case cause the problem because of the actions of the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Looks OK to me, and works fine when I run it on a Linux Desktop in a debugger.

Suggestions are;

1. char *c points to an invalid address, or
2. some weird compiler bug in the compiler you are using is unable to initialized the `char some[3]` -- try to break it up in simpler assignment statements, or
3. The possibility of `threadIdx.x` being negative? i.e. if threadIdx.x is -1 then c[i] is c[-1] which may not be valid...

Comment: You didn't run this on a GPU did you?